# Two versions of the Inverse Function Theorem.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I first learned about the Inverse Function Theorem for $C^1$ functions in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* in the following form.

> **Inverse Function Theorem ($C^1$ version):** Suppose $E$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:E\to\mathbb{R}^n$ ***is a $C^1$ mapping***. If $f'(a)$ is invertible for some $a\in E$, and $b=f(a)$, then there exist neighborhoods $U$ of $a$ and $V$ of $b$ such that $f:U\to V$ is invertible and $f^{-1}:V\to U$ ***is also a $C^1$ mapping***.

But I recently encountered the following version for $C^\infty$ functions.

> **Inverse Function Theorem ($C^\infty$ version):** Suppose $E$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:E\to\mathbb{R}^n$ ***is a $C^\infty$ mapping***. If $f'(a)$ is invertible for some $a\in E$, and $b=f(a)$, then there exist neighborhoods $U$ of $a$ and $V$ of $b$ such that $f:U\to V$ is invertible and $f^{-1}:V\to U$ ***is also a $C^\infty$ mapping***.

Now my question: Can we prove the second one from the first? Or do we have to redo the proof for the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because the first gives a formula for the derivative.

Since $D(f^{-1})(f(x)) = (Df(x))^{-1}$, and the mapping $A \mapsto A^{-1}$ is
smooth, we see that the mapping $x \mapsto D(f^{-1})(f(x))$ is as smooth as
$Df$ (which is $C^\infty$).

Now consider the function $y \mapsto D(f^{-1})(y)$ around $y=f(x)$.

The function $f^{-1}$ is a $C^1$ mapping, hence the
mapping $y \mapsto D(f^{-1})(f(f^{-1}(y)))$ is a $C^1$ mapping.
This in turn implies that $f^{-1}$ is a $C^2$ mapping.

In general, we can use the formula to conclude that if $f^{-1}$ is a $C^k$
mapping then it is a $C^{k+1}$ mapping, from which it follows that $f^{-1}$
is $C^\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Why "This in turn implies that $f^{-1}$ is a $C^2$ mapping"?

Comment: You see that $x \mapsto D(f^{-1})(f(x))$ is $C^\infty$?

Comment: Nevermind, I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: It is a little subtle.